# jQuery give Url at contact form

Tags: jquery

I do not know a lot about jquery, but I'm looking for a solution for this problem.
I need to extrapolate the last parameter of the URL, if it is equal to "adv_source = AdWords" then I must return "AdWords", otherwise I must give "SEO".
This is what I managed to do until now.
Can anyone help me?

```
var url=jQuery('[_url]').val(); 

if (url.search("adv_source=AdWords")) seoadwords = "Adwords";
else seoadwords = "SEO";
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does that url actually do anything? You can get the current url in jquery like this `var url = $(location).attr('href');`

Comment: Why would you even use jQuery to do that?  `location.href` works just fine.  Just because jQuery is helpful in many cases, doesn't mean it has to **always** be used.

Comment: I have to insert the field in the contact form,** I do not know if it is the best way** but I have to be able to say that "http://www.xxxx.com/xxxxxxxxx/?adv_source=AdWords" has only this inside "? adv_source = AdWords "and then turn it into" Adwords "instead if it is not so, it must return" seo ".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working solution :

```
   let searchParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search) //get URL
   searchParams.has('adv_source'); //Search the parameter adv_source
   let param = searchParams.get('adv_source'); //search the value
   if(param == "AdWords"){
      seoadwords = "Adwords";
   }else{
      seoadwords = "SEO";
   }
```

I found the solution here : [Get url parameter jquery Or How to Get Query String Values In js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19491336/get-url-parameter-jquery-or-how-to-get-query-string-values-in-js)

Or shorter solution:

```
var parameter = (location.search.split('adv_source' + '=')[1] || '').split('&')[0];
if(parameter == "AdWords"){
    seoadwords = "Adwords";
}else{
    seoadwords = "SEO";
}
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Make sure to take note of browser support.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/URLSearchParams

Comment: It's ok in the second solution.

Comment: Ok, I'll try with the second one.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the format of your url's you can do

```
var url = $(location).attr('href');
if (url.contains('adv_source=AdWords')) {
    var seowords = 'Adwords';
}
else {
  var seowords = 'SEO';
}

console.log(seowords);
```